# gps not providing correct co-ordinates

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I've developed an application in android. Its a **Vehicle Tracking System** which uses `GPS`.
The application send the latitude and longitude co-ordinates which stores in an online mysql database, which it is been take by the java web application to draw path with which the device have traveled. The application also calculates distance between two co-ordinates, and based upon that distance it send the latitude and longitude co-ordinates, i.e from one point to another if the device covers a distance of 20 meters at that point it sends the latitude and longitude co-ordinates to the web-application for storing and drawing in google-map.

**The problem**

The application works fine but the problem is when the application is been started and when kept at a place without any movement, it is sending some co-ordinates which is not correct. for example in the below picture when the device reached a stop (black spot in google-map), actually for a time being it should been at that spot, instead as shown in the picture the device is been going somewhere and coming and again going somewhere even if the device is not moving.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me some solutions to prevent this

These are my permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

**UPDATION 1**

```
 LocationManager mlocmag = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
         LocationListener mlocList = new MyLocationList();

                Location loc1 = mlocmag.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (loc1 == null) {
                    loc1 = mlocmag.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                }

           String  lat =loc1.getLatitude();
           String  Longs = loc1.getLongitude();
```

Comment: Are you using Network Provider by any chance?

Comment: But i think you can draw the line using googlemap methods.so why you are using java or anything to draw the paths.

Comment: stop using wifi to set your location, check if this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should disable (GSM-)cell-tower locationing, use GPS only, by only using GPS_PROVIDER
 And set to highest quality.

Forget that NETWORK_PROVIDER this is not made for accurate vehicle tracking.
NETWORK location can be off by 1000m.
 The network provider is usefull to know in which city a device is.

Comment: explicitly set the GPS_PROVIDER as location Provider, search here on Stackoverflow for GPS_PROVIDER

Comment: also can you please take a look at my UPDATION 1......is that code causes any problem

Comment: This line makes no sense: loc1 = mlocmag.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

Comment: Just wait till you get GPS. If you don't get GPS, then don't try another source. Indoors there is no tracking. Wait till you get GPS

Answer (score 0):

I highly suspect the role of GPS accuracy in this case,

Android apps try to access precise location from location sources such as GPS, cell towers, and Wi-Fi when `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission is given in manifest, the primary and (super) location provider are GPS satellites which have accuracy of 0m - 20m. when GPS satellites are out of range or phone is indoor, android will seek other means of location provider, one of them is cell ID, which uses cell phone tower triangulation to find the approximate location of the device with an accuracy of around 200m - 2000m. When there are more than 4 cell tower near your area the the cell triangulation shifts tower to tower causing the sensation of moving.

Using old android permissions like

```
android.permission.ACCESS_GPS
android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS
android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_CELL_ID
```

May fix your problem with approximate location mockups.

Try using a different phone or location for different results.

However if the problem still persists the problem could be your code or your phone itself, in such case I would need parts of code for further help.

Comment: do you mean that i should remove android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION from my manifest file

Comment: Yes, 
The permissions I stated technically will work for android 1 - 4 APIs Not sure whether it still works (I've not used it for a while) why don't you give it a try

Answer (score 0):

The problem is prbably caused by the vehicle being parked in a garage or similar with poor GPS satellite reception in which case the signal loses accuracy and can appear to wander randomly.

Your app should monitor the GPS signal strength and number of satellites being received and disregard positions whilst signal strength is too low.
There are a number of apps available that show signal strength

Comment: so do you mean that i should first check the signal strength and based upon the strength....i should send the latitude and longitude.....